# Android App Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I need to create an android app that receives data via a bluetooth connection. I am doing some android programming but i can't quite grasp it. Could somebody offer some guidance on where to start. I know a little bit of java. I have downloaded all the neccesary software. COuld somebody refer a usefull link that teaches java or android programming?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good book for beginning android development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development)

Answer (score 1):

The canonical reference is the Android Bluetooth development guide at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html, and the Bluetooth Chat example at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to amazon, and the many books on Android. There are many websites that teach Java and Android, google it ;)

Specificly in regards to bluetooth you may refer to chapter 7 of the [Android Developer Cookbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=Q9KZSQAACAAJ&dq=Android%20Developer%E2%80%99s%20Cookbook%3a&hl=en&ei=OOqaTYn9NsPl4waQnYCZBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA)

Answer (score 1):

I am new to android too (Atleast I was new 3 weeks ago!). The links given above are quite helpful to create most android apps. For Java, refer to [the oracle java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), they are quite good.
Best of luck!